I want to update the next-auth session from a NULL state
I have built an app using the Zoom app sdk. The expected flow is if the user is logged in Zoom, he is supposed to get logged into my app automatically. This is done by exchanging the tokens from Zoom with my app's tokens. I am using NextJS 14 and the next-auth setup.
I tried updating the session using the update() function provided by next-auth. But it didn't work. It seems like the session needs to be NOT NULL for the update() function to work.
Any way I could tackle this problem. Do I need to create a fake session first or create a new login flow for this scenario?
Thanks in advance!
